# Proper terminology for Artificial Intelligence in games

Tags: terminology, artificial-intelligence

I was curious if game A.I. had a technical term since it's not really Artificial Intelligence, but rather the illusion of intelligence. Or is it simply just called [Game A.I.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Game_artificial_intelligence)? Is there a term in another field that represents the same thing?

Comment: Isn't the point of calling it "artificial" intelligence instead of "natural" because it is entirely an illusion? The programming routines used to setup the actions of very complex NPCs is on a similar level to the logical processes needed to construct any other kind of AI.

Comment: Game A.I.'s the term. Also neural networks, a field in itself, is a part of A.I.'s.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, I hadn't thought of it that way.

Comment: Please don't be offended that this got closed as off-topic. Some AI topics are naturally fit here, but the subject of industry and technical terminology is somewhat borderline and probably better suited on a site like the [Game Development Stack Exchange](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com). And in the end, you still got your question answered, so nothing truly lost!

Comment: Yeah that's fine, it was meant to relate to gaming, but game development is probably a better place to post it. Thanks for the input.

Comment: Don't focus too much on the recent success deep learning and neural network technology as AI. There are many types of AI. Previously successful AI technology such as fuzzy logic and statistical filtering (eg. Bayesian filter) are not commonly thought of as AI by programmers these days because they seem so normal but they are also AI. In fact one of the earliest success of AI is actually the program `make` (what you write Makefiles for). At its core is an expert system that automatically build and resolve dependency graphs (unfortunately most people write Makefiles that break it)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**All** artificial intelligence is merely an illusion of true intelligence. This doesn't change depending on the environment, including video games.

In the industry, [we do call it A.I.](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/ijcaiigames/)

Comment: Ah, I guess I didn't think about it that way. I was thinking more along the lines of "real/conceptual A.I." being able to interpret and make decisions on its own, rather than having scripted reactions.

Comment: That's exactly what modern A.I. is - the ability to think and learn and grow with the player. For example, one of the first advanced artificially advanced agents was a chess player that got better as you played against it. This can be seen more and more in recent video games.

Comment: "All artificial intelligence is merely an illusion of true intelligence"? That is a matter of opinion not a matter of fact. Some would say that your own consciousness / free will is an illusion. It's not a useful point of view.

Answer (score 1):

Thing is, what is taught in college as AI is as much Artificial Intelligence as a rubber duck is Artificial Life. There is no known algorithm that replicates animal or human intelligence yet. Everything we know as AI should be better described as "simulated intelligence".